# Set grails domain object property without calling the setter method

Tags: grails, groovy

Domain `Person` has property `name`.
The setter method has been overridden to store the name embedded inside an internationalization object within the person object as:

```
internationalization: {
    name: {
       en: engilshName,
       fr: frenchName
    }
}
```

Therefore the piece of code:

```
def person = new Person()
person.setName('Merhawi', new Locale('en'))
person.setName('frenchMerhawi', new Locale('fr'))
person.save()
```

would store my name inside a mongo database as:

```
{
    _id: NumberLong(1),
    internationalization: {
        name: {
           en: "Merhawi",
           fr: "frenchMerhawi"
        }
    }
}
```

Invoking `getName` on person would return the correct name depending on the current locale of the environment.

**Now what I am trying to do is:** get `person` as `JSON` data so I want an extra field name that contains the correct name depending on the current locale of the environment besides to the other fields. Trying to set `person.name = person.getName()` before returning `person` as `grails.converters.JSON` would call the setter method and it doesn't give an extra name field. It instead tries to store the name in the same embedded manner.

How do I add extra name field without calling the setter method?

Answer (score 1):

```
person.metaClass.setName = {-> delegate.name = delegate.getName()}
person.setName();
return [person] as grails.converters.JSON
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the reason you ended up with this challenge is that the `Person.name` property breaks the contract of what a property is.

For example, consider the confusion something like this would cause:

```
person.name = 'John Smith'
println person.name    //<--- Actually prints 'Jane Doe'
```

In your case, `Person.name` acts more like a method, yet the naming convention suggests it's a property, yet it doesn't act like a property. What goes in doesn't come out.

## A better way

I think you'd be better off:

1. allowing the `name` property to work like a real property (ex.
   `person.name = object`)
2. modifying `person.setName(String, Locale)` (or naming the method something else all together) to be a convenience method that would create the object that `person.name` expects (ex. `def setName(String name, Locale locale) { this.name = new Object(name, locale) }` )
3. adding a method to the class of `person.name` to return the name based on the current locale. That would allow you to access the correct name with something like this: `person.name.toLocalized()`. You can also have a `name.toLocalized(String locale)` to get a name for a specific locale.

Comment: The domain classes are not accessible to me. I can't just change the overriden methods the way I want. In fact the methods were overriden inside Bootstrap.groovy using AST. But I don't see how the third options solves the problem. All I wanted was get an additional property name at the top level of the object (i.e. not embedded)

Comment: You can use something like `person.localizedName()` instead. But pretending that a property is something other than what it is, inevitably leads to Code Smell. The fact that you have to override `setName()`, and call it so that it can 'fix' the name, before you can use it in a JSON conversion is evidence of this; it's an early warning. Sometimes we have to deal with bad code that cannot be changed. Ultimately, in such cases the best approach is damage control: code that sits between your code and the bad stuff so that the cancer doesn't spread.